# Bash script to launch app and login - gets stuck, cursor doesn't move down the page

Tags: android, bash, shell, input, adb

What I want to do: Clear the data, then launch my app. On the first page, tab down and agree to conditions, then on next page tab down to the sign-in textfields, enter the username, password, then tap sign in.

What happens is the data is cleared, the app is launched, then the app just sits on the terms/conditions screen, and the cursor does not move down to the buttons.

What am I missing? Do I need to bring the focus to the screen so that the cursor gets a location before I move it?

```
#!/bash/src

adb shell pm clear com.myapp.package
adb shell am start -n com.myapp.package/com.myapp.package.Main
adb shell input keyevent 20 
adb shell input keyevent 20
adb shell input keyevent 20
adb shell input keyevent 20
adb shell input keyevent 21
adb shell input keyevent 66
adb shell input text "username"
adb shell input keyevent 20
adb shell input text "password"
adb shell input keyevent 20
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try sending a back button to see if you can dismiss the Terms and conditions:

```
adb shell input keyevent 4
```